# Why won't this PIC code light up my LEDs?

Tags: c, pic, pic18, mplab

The following code won't set any of the pins high on my PIC18F14K50, yet it couldn't be simpler!

```
#include <pic18.h>
#include <htc.h>

void main(void)
{
  // Set ALL pins to output:
  TRISA = 0;
  TRISB = 0;
  TRISC = 0;

  // Set ALL pins to high:
  LATA = 0b11111111;
  LATB = 0b11111111;
  LATC = 0b11111111;

  // Leave pins high and wait forever:
  while (1);
}
```

I'm using MPLAB v8.43 and the Hi-Tech ANSI C Compiler.

A logic probe shows none of the pins high except the VUSB and the MCLR.

Any ideas?

Comment: The program looks OK, but was it loaded?, is it really running? Your problem may have other reasons

Comment: Try creating a simple counter (unsigned char counter or similar), initialize it to zero, and let the while loop increment it and set the outputs to the value of the counter variable...? Just to make sure that something is actually happening - that's always easier to debug than static output.

Comment: There is no _CONFIG for you processor show in the code snippet. What clock source are you trying to use ? Internal on chip or do you have an Xtal conntected to chip?

Comment: Probably a good idea to clear the watchdog in the while loop to prevent it causing resets. Unless your config bits disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least some of the pins may be configured as Analog Inputs.

From the Datasheet for this device

> The operation of pin RA4 as analog is selected by setting the ANS3
>   bit in the ANSEL register which is the default set-ting after a
>   Power-on Reset.

If you do not set the ANSEL register the pin cannot be used as output as it is configured as an analog input.

This applies to all the pins that can be A/D inputs, which does not cover all the pins you have.

Then again I do not see any configuration bit setup in your code. That device e.g. has 2 different instruction sets and you have to at the very least specify which instruction set you are using in the configuration bits.

You may try adding this to the top of your code just after the includes :

```
// Configuration BITS setup
__CONFIG(1, FOSC_INTIO2 & XINST_OFF);
__CONFIG(2, WDTEN_OFF & PWRTEN_ON);
__CONFIG(3, MCLRE_OFF);
```

Comment: Setting `ANSEL` and `ANSELH` to `0` did the trick. I also disabled the extra instruction set - I don't know if that had any effect but I read in a few places that it's best to disable if not needed. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you didn't configure the MCPU oscillator, try to define:

```
;   Oscillator:
    config  FOSC = INTIO2           ;Internal RC oscillator
;
;   PLL x4 Enable bit:
    config  PLLCFG = OFF
```

and

```
;Define oscillator frequency 
;{
    movlw   b'01100000'
    movwf   OSCCON
    movlw   b'01000000'
    movwf   OSCTUNE
;};
```

This directives are for MPLAB asm and not for Hi-Tech, but file registers should have the same names.